# for every $v$ vector If $Av = Bv$ then $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I just can't grasp the idea, I mean I can give you billion vectors and matrices for which this
sentence is not correct.
take vector which build with multiple zeros and whatever different $A,B$ matrices you want
Can someone shed some light

Comment: It's not "for any" vector, it's "for all" vectors. Choose an $A$ and $B$ ahead of time, then if it is true that $Av = Bv$ _for all vectors_ $v$, then we must have $A = B$.

Comment: Where did you find this statement? Maybe it's not supposed to be true? You could try showing it in context, and be sure to quote it accurately. (By the way, it doesn't work to ask a question like this in the title; you can fit part of the question there, but it works better if you write the full version of the question below the title so that it would still make sense if the title were erased.)

Answer (score 2):

If $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$, then notice that
$$Ae_j = j\text{-th column of $A$}, \quad Be_j = j\text{-th column of $B$}$$

If $Av = Bv$ for every vector $v$, then in particular $Ae_j = Be_j$ for all $1 \le j \le n$ so $A$ and $B$ have equal columns i.e. $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

Two maps $A,B$ are equal if they have the same domain, and the same action on each element in the domain

Sorry I cannot comment yet!

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ and $B$ agree on any vector, then in particular they agree on a basis.  This implies that they agree everywhere, as the values on a basis determine a linear transformation.

Answer (score 0):

So After I racked my brain for a good day I will answer my own question for future readers:
The reason why you can not simply use vector of zeros or any other specific vector with any other specific matrices to disprove the sentence is the fact that If you give a specific example for A,B and v where Av=Bv but A!=B It does not necessarily mean Av=Bv for *EVERY* vector.

```
Let v = 0     A= 1 0    B= 1 0
        0        0 0      -1 0
```

You simply can not guarantee Av and Bv are equal for all the other vectors

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is just a linear transformation, if two transformations act exactly the same way on every possible input, they are the same transformation.